# restart terminated emr cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services

I terminated an existing cluster to not incur costs. Can I somehow restart this cluster. Is cloning = restart? Thanks and sorry about my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, cloning is not restarting.

If you fully automated your cluster with, i.e., bootstrap actions and cluster steps, then cloning will be the exact same. It takes the configuration and re-launches that. But if you SSH'd in and executed manual commands, you will not be able to get that back..

One of the key things with EMR is that it is ephemeral

Comment: I think the above question is only partially answered. As said above "cloning is not restarting" and we can clone the cluster. However still the question remains whether one can restart a terminated cluster or not.